# About NodeJS Buffers

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, buffer

Question about buffers.
if i have this native code:

```
unsigned char* data = static_cast<unsigned char*>(malloc(sizeof(int) * 4));
Napi::Buffer<unsigned char> buffer = Napi::Buffer::New(info.Env(), data, sizeof(int) * 4); // create buffer

return buffer;
```

it would return the buffer to js, does the GC handle the `malloc`'d data? or would it cause a leak since i didn't free it. The reason i asked this here is because i am dealing with **js** buffers

Comment: malloc?? in javascript ... no such animal

Comment: that `malloc` was done natively, not js itself. The code i showed is an example of what i'm doing natively for the buffer

Comment: you don't have to worry - javascript handles memory for you

Comment: Unless you're specifically instructed to use `malloc`, try and use `new[]` in C++ for allocations like this. Even better, `std::vector` and `data()` if applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should manually free it use other overload

https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/master/doc/buffer.md#new-2

> The Napi::Buffer object does not assume ownership for the data and expects it to be valid for the lifetime of the object. The data can only be freed once the finalizeCallback is invoked to indicate that the Napi::Buffer has been released.

> ```
> template <typename Finalizer>
> static Napi::Buffer<T> Napi::Buffer::New(napi_env env
>    T* data,
>    size_t length,
>    Finalizer finalizeCallback);
> ```

---

note : I haven't use NAPI before but I think it's the correct document.

Comment: in the callback, should i use the `delete` operator or just the `free` function?

Comment: @Alexander if you `malloc` then `free`, if you `new`, then `delete`